# DbContext "using" in a single line

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda, extension-methods

I find myself doing this a lot:

```
using(var db = new MyDbContext())
{
  return db.Users.ToList(); // or some other simple query
}
```

It would be nice to these simple cases as something like:

```
return MyDbContext.Execute(db => db.Users);
```

but I'm not sure how I would do the extension method.  Ideally (i think) it would take a DbContext (so I could reuse the code) and return the templated IList.. but is this possible?

Of course, if there's already a method that does this I would love to hear about it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write the simplest of static classes for this.  You don't want an extension method, because that requires an instance (and based on the syntax in your example, you don't yet have one):

```
public static class MyDbContextStatic { 
    public static T Execute(Func<MyDbContext, T> f) {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
            return f(db);
    }
}
```

To use:

```
var users = MyDbContextStatic.Execute(db => db.Users);
```

IIRC, you probably want to call Detach or something on each object before disposing the DbContext as well.  But you get the idea.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!!   Though it would be nice if there was a way to do this on the underlying DbContext..

Comment: @SteveLamb there is, of course.  Just put the static `Execute` method in the code for the DbContext.  I was assuming that the DbContext is a generated, non-partial class, and so your code would be overwritten by the code generator.  If it is a partial class, you could put the static method in a separate file.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is the proper way to do it, it makes sure to call `Dispose` after the end of the block, that will cause the connection to be closed. You may comeup with an extension method to do your work, But it will require you to have a reference to `DbContext` in memory for static `DbContext`.

With respect to database connection, you should open them as late as possible and close as early as possible.

Comment: Yeah I updated the scenario since it would have to be an IList.  But the same concept still holds.. is that possible?

Comment: @SteveLamb, not sure, may be you can return `obj.ToList().AsQueryable();`, but again, I would rather follow the conventions, because having an extension method may cause some problems.

Answer (score 0):

DbContext manages the underlying connection for you.
You can call Dispose, but in most common scenarios you don’t need to.

http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html